# Replacing the whole state within a reducer usint Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

the title sounds wired, but what happens if I collect data from a server and in a reducer, I simply want to return these data and set them as the new state.

E.g. fetching data from a backend. Do I really need to make a copy of the previous state if I want to replace it like this:

```
export function accountData(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_FAILURE:
      console.error('SOMETHING BAD JUST HAPPENED');
      break;
    case FETCH_SUCCESS:
        return Object.assign([], state, action.accountData);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

or would it be ok in this case to just do this:

```
export function accountData(state = [], action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_FAILURE:
          console.error('SOMETHING BAD JUST HAPPENED');
          break;
        case FETCH_SUCCESS:
            return action.accountData;
        default:
          return state;
      }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "_would it be ok_"? If the code does what you want it to do, what's the problem?

Comment: aside: is your default `state` really an array?

Comment: Yeah its an array of accounts. I always read about not mutating the state which I actually do if I would just return the accounts without copying it..

Comment: You're mutating state either way, whether you merge the old state or replace it wholesale. Related, using `Object.assign` with arrays strikes me as odd? Are you sure that does what you think it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can replace the entire state.* `Object.assign` is simply a convenience method to replace part of the state whilst leaving everything else in tact, and doing so in an immutable fashion. If you're replacing the entire state then it's not necessary to use `Object.assign`.

(*When I say state I mean the portion of the state for which the reducer is responsible.)

Furthermore it makes no sense to use `Object.assign` for an array. <s>`Object.assign([], state, action.accountData);` is semantically equivalent to `Object.assign([], action.accountData);` That is, it creates a new copy of the array. But since it's an array an not an object, a more explicit and intuitive way to write it would be `action.accountData.slice(0)` or `[...action.accountData]`.</s> [**CORRECTION:** In fact, `Object.assign` does index-for-index replacement on arrays, which is almost certainly NOT what you want.]

So long as you treat the array is read-only, you can return the array by itself without copying it. So the final way you've written it - `return action.accountData;` - is perfectly correct.

Finally, I must take issue with the `FETCH_FAILURE` case. You're not returning anything for this action. But your reducer should always return *something*. Instead of `break;` you should probably have either `return state;` or `return [];` depending on exactly how you want to treat the failure case.

Comment: Your explanation of applying `Object.assign` to an array is wrong; it still does a shallow merge. Try it: `Object.assign([], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d']) // -> ['d', 'b', 'c']`

Comment: hey. thx. The fetch_failure case return something, I just removed it from the snippet to keep it cleaner ;)