# Replacing new state in react redux reducer without making a copy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

If I have completely replacing the entirety of a slice of state, do I still have to use Object.assign or the spread operator to make a copy of the original state and replace it with the new state, or can I just return the new state in my reducer?

```
const fetching = (state = { isFetching: false }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'REQUESTING':
      return Object.assign({}, state, { isFetching: true } )
    case 'RECEIVE_POKEMON_TYPE_INFO':
      return Object.assign({}, state, { isFetching: false } )
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

vs.

```
const fetching = (state = { isFetching: false }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'REQUESTING':
      return { isFetching: true }
    case 'RECEIVE_POKEMON_TYPE_INFO':
      return { isFetching: false }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: If you can replace `return Object.assign({}, state, { isFetching: true } )` with `return Object.assign({}, { isFetching: true } )` , then you can replace it with `{ isFetching: true }`. Otherwise, you cannot because rest of state will be lost.

Comment: I think there's a similar question has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35002802/1973908)

Comment: I think there's a similar question has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35002802/1973908).

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of things going on here. Basically, if your state *only* consists of a boolean variable, then creating a new object by enumeration is OK. However, if your state consists of other things, then doing an object.assign should work.

However (and isn't there always a 'however'), if your state is complex - that is it consists of other objects then doing object.assign will not properly copy the fields - it copied the references not the values. For example, if your state consists of a "currentlySelectedPokemon" field there the value is a Pokemon object, then Object.assign will copy a reference to the pokemon object. It won't copy the object itself. To show this more easily, look at the code below - it prints "value2" for obj2.

```js
var obj1 = {
  field: {
    subfield: "value"
  }
};

var obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj1);

obj1.field.subfield = "value2";

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj2, null, 2));
```

There are two ways to get around this. The first is to use the Immutable library for all your state. However, I found the overhead of converting complex objects into Immutable and back provided enough complexity that it introduced unnecessary bugs. So now I do this:

```js
const fetching = (state = { isFetching: false }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'REQUESTING':
      const newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
      newState.isFetching = true;
      return newState;
    case 'RECEIVE_POKEMON_TYPE_INFO':
      const newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
      newState.isFetching = false;
      return newState;
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

It turns out that JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object)) is a fast reliable way to make a copy of a vanilla java object. It strips all functions (which is what I generally want). And it's fast because browsers usually implement those functions in native code.

Comment: why is it ok for just a boolean and not ok if I have other pieces of data? as long as I replace a single piece of data, can't I just return a new object that will replace the old state?

Comment: There are several problems. The one that hurts me the most is that if other code that mutates the data after putting it in the store, it can also change the data in the store. That causes some very odd issues that are hard to track down - because the Redux store is changing but Redux is not sending change notifications.

Comment: so the process of making a copy of the old state and then replacing it with the new state rather than just not making a copy and replacing it with new state somehow ensures that the redux store's change will cause redux to send out notifications?

Comment: What it means is your store will not change when some other code sets the state and then changes the object it used to set the state. So the store will only change when something is explicitly dispatched.

Answer (score 1):

you can either use `Object.assign` or `spread operator`, like below

**using `Object.assign`:**

```
const fetching = (state = { isFetching: false }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'REQUESTING':
      return Object.assign({}, state, { isFetching: true } )
    case 'RECEIVE_POKEMON_TYPE_INFO':
      return Object.assign({}, state, { isFetching: false } )
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

**using spread operator:**

```
const fetching = (state = { isFetching: false }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'REQUESTING':
      return { ...state, isFetching: true }
    case 'RECEIVE_POKEMON_TYPE_INFO':
      return { ...state, isFetching: false }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

using `Object.assign()` can quickly make simple reducers difficult to read given its rather `verbose syntax`.the `spread (...)` operator to copy enumerable properties from one object to another in a more succinct way.

Comment: Note that this only does a "shallow copy", meaning keys at the top/root level of the object are cloned, but any object (and maybe primitive? not sure.) below the top level simply gets referenced, not copied.